# Url.Action returns %2F in link instead of slash generated from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have been struggling to get this working for couple of hours now. In my controller I have a method for Registration new users. Then I have following code in this method:

```
  string token = await this.UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(newUser);
  string confirmationLink = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "api/Authorize", new { token, email = newUser.Email }, Request.Scheme);
  Message message = new Message(new string[] { newUser.Email }, "Confirmation email link", confirmationLink, null);
  await this.EmailSender.SendEmailAsync(message);
```

As a result, I am getting the following link to my email:

```
https://localhost:5000/api%2FAuthorize/...
```

Whereas you can see instead of slash there is a `%2F`. How to get this working in a proper way?

I have found some solutions where you simply use string replace, but this looks like a workaround for me rather than a proper way of writing correct code.

Comment: Um, is this ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: You have a forward slash in the name.  Change the name and the issue will not occur.

Comment: @jdweng my controller has following `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` so there should be this "api/Authorize"... or do you mean something else?

Comment: The second parameter is "controller", so if your controller is called `BobController` then that value should be `"Bob"`, not a route.

Comment: The character 0x2F is a forward slash and in HTML is a special character and must be replaced.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: The method you're using expects the first two parameters to be the action and controller name, not a URL. As they're names not URLs, they're being escaped: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-urlhelperextensions-action(microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-iurlhelper-system-string-system-string-system-object-system-string)

Comment: @MartinCostello I think I understand that part, but then what is the solution to get it working?

Comment: If your controller is named `AdminController`, then you'd need to specify `"Admin"`.

Comment: @MartinCostello my controller has following `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` so there should be this "api/Authorize" and controller name is AuthorizeController

Comment: So you want `Authorize` for the controller name. The route is used to generate the URL for the action, which `Url.Action()` uses.

Comment: @MartinCostello I have "api" prefix before my controller. I want to somehow add this into my link before Controller name, so that the end result would have "/" slash instead of %2F

Comment: The `Url.Action()` method is used to generate URLs for you. It will add it automatically provided you call it correctly with the _action name_ and _controller name_.